# PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser issue

Tags: php, html

I have a section of html code like this :

```
      <a>
             <img scr=""/>some text here...
      </a>

      <a>
             <img scr=""/>some text here...
      </a>
```

I need to get the some text here...

i was trying like this : 
                      let say the section above is in a html dom.$html

```
foreach ($html->find('a') as $myText)
{
      echo '-----PPPP---->>>>'.$myText->plaintext.'this is test<br/>';   
}
```

But it's printing the text and image both.I just need the text

Comment: Odd. `->plaintext` should only retrieve text nodes from the node you're dealing with. `->innertext` would return child nodes as well as the text.

Comment: Simple HTML DOM Parser has it's issues, probably that's one of them. You could change to a better parser like [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/DOMDocument) and then just use an xpath expression to obtain the text.

Answer (score 1):

```
->find('a')->plaintext;
```

should do it

Answer (score 0):

I didn't use Simple HTML DOM Parser but instead went with [DomDocument](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php):

```
$html = <<<HTML
<a><img src=""/>some text here...</a>
<a><img scr=""/>some text here...</a>
HTML;

$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$links = $dom->getElementsByTagName("a");
foreach ($links as $link) {
    var_dump($link->textContent);
}
```

results in:

```
string 'some text here...' (length=17)
string 'some text here...' (length=17)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about splitting it into two parts and printing after image tag:

```
foreach ($html->find('a') as $myText)
{
   $parts = explode("/>", $myText);
   echo $parts[1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use DOMDocument in PHP.

Like this:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->load($htmlfile);
$atags = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
foreach ($atags as $atag) {
    echo $atag->textContent;
}
```